# Cross platform push messaging - Native or Phonegap/Titanium?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, native

I need to develop as simple app for messaging. It will use GCM and APNS.
I have some experience with JS/jQuery.

Should I learn both eclipse/java and xcode/object c, or would using phonegap (or titanium) make my life easier? So far trying to make cordova work I just run into compatibility issues...

I plan to use my own php push server.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the strong platform capabilities then you need to learn both eclipse/java and xcode/ objective C. If you want to provide the users with the native interface and controls they are accustomed to.

But if you are planning to have your interface which works across both platforms and you take a slight performance issue versus the cost of development in multiple platforms.

But in any case, you need to learn eclipse and xcode for deployment and code structing. Also, if you want to communicate to the OS you need to write the plugins in the native.

Hope you can make your choice now.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Interface is less of an issue, the app is quite simple.

I do realize need to learn at least basics of Eclipse/Xcode.
It does seem that using Cordova will allow me to reuse at least some of the code. Plus, I really enjoy jQuery syntax.